# I tried creating an update and add function. When you add and update a customer, it makes all the fields null

Tags: php, mysql, t-sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

The application is C-Manager

http://github.com/MathewBaldwin

Here is the edit function

```
<?php include('includes/database.php'); ?>
<?php
    //Assign get variable
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    //Create customer select query
    $query ="SELECT * FROM customers
             INNER JOIN customer_addresses
             ON customer_addresses.customer=customers.id
             WHERE customers.id = $id";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
    if($result = $mysqli->query($query)){
        //Fetch object array
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $first_name = $row['first_name'];
            $last_name = $row['last_name'];
            $email = $row['email'];
            $password = $row['password'];
            $address = $row['address'];
            $address2 = $row['address2'];
            $city = $row['city'];
            $state = $row['state'];
            $zipcode = $row['zipcode'];
        }
        //Free Result set
        $result->close();
    }
?>
<?php
    if($_POST){
        //Assign GET Variable
        $id = $_GET['id'];

        //Assign Variables
        $first_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['first_name']);
        $last_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['last_name']);
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
        $address = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
        $address2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address2']);
        $city = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['city']);
        $state = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['state']);
        $zipcode = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['zipcode']);

        //Create customer update
        $query = "UPDATE customers
                  SET
                  first_name='$first_name',
                  last_name='$last_name',
                  email='$email',
                  password='$password'
                  WHERE id=$id
                  ";
        $mysqli->query($query) or die();

        //Create address update
        $query = "UPDATE customer_addresses
                  SET
                  address='$address',
                  address2='$address2',
                  city='$city',
                  state='$state',
                  zipcode='$zipcode'
                  WHERE customer=$id
                  ";
        $mysqli->query($query) or die();
        $msg="Customer Updated";
        header('Location:index.php?msg='.urlencode($msg).'');
        exit;
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>CManager | Edit Customer</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/jumbotron-narrow.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
          <li ><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="add_customer.php">Add Customer</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h3 class="text-muted">Store CManager</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="row marketing">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
         <h2>Edit Customer</h2>
         <form role="form" method="post" action="edit_customer.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>First Name</label>
                <input name="first_name" type="text" class="form-control" 
                value="<?php echo $first_name; ?>" placeholder="Enter First Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Last Name</label>
                <input name="last_name" type="text" class="form-control" 
                value="<?php echo $last_name; ?>" placeholder="Enter Last Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email address</label>
                <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" 
                value="<?php echo $email; ?>" placeholder="Enter Email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" 
                value="<?php echo $password; ?>" placeholder="Enter Password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Address</label>
                <input name="address" type="text" class="form-control" 
                value="<?php echo $address; ?>" placeholder="Enter Address">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Address 2</label>
                <input name="address2" type="text" class="form-control" 
                value="<?php echo $address2; ?>" placeholder="Enter Address 2">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>City</label>
                <input name="city" type="text" class="form-control" 
                value="<?php echo $city; ?>" placeholder="Enter City">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>State</label>
                <input name="state" type="text" class="form-control" 
                value="<?php echo $state; ?>" placeholder="Enter State">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Zipcode</label>
                <input name="zipcode" type="text" class="form-control" 
                value="<?php echo $zipcode; ?>" placeholder="Enter Zipcode">
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Update Customer" />
        </form>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="footer">
        <p>&copy; Company 2014</p>
      </div>

    </div> <!-- /container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
  </body>
</html>
```

and here is the add function

```
<?php include('includes/database.php'); ?>
<?php
    if($_POST){
        //Get variables from post array
        $first_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['first_name']);
        $last_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['last_name']); 
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']); 
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['password'])); 
        $address = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
        $address2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address2']);
        $city = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['city']);
        $state= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['state']);
        $zipcode = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['zipcode']);

        //Create customer query
        $query ="INSERT INTO customers (first_name,last_name,email,password)
                                VALUES ('$first_name','$last_name','$email','$password')";
        //Run query
        $mysqli->query($query);

        //Create address query
        $query ="INSERT INTO customer_addresses (customer,address,address2,city,state,zipcode)
                                VALUES ('$mysqli->insert_id','$address','$address2','$city','$state','$zipcode')";
        //Run query
        $mysqli->query($query);

        $msg='Customer Added';
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit;
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>CManager | Add Customer</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/jumbotron-narrow.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
          <li ><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="add_customer.php">Add Customer</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h3 class="text-muted">Store CManager</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="row marketing">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
         <h2>Add Customer</h2>
         <form role="form" method="post" action="add_customer.php">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>First Name</label>
                <input name="first_name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Last Name</label>
                <input name="last_name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Last Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email address</label>
                <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Address</label>
                <input name="address" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Address">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Address 2</label>
                <input name="address2" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Address 2">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>City</label>
                <input name="city" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter City">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>State</label>
                <input name="state" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter State">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Zipcode</label>
                <input name="zipcode" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Zipcode">
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Add Customer" />
        </form>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="footer">
        <p>&copy; Company 2014</p>
      </div>

    </div> <!-- /container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Whenever I try to add a new customer or update an already existing one, it creates a blank customer even if you fill out all the forms. I am not sure what to do.

Comment: are you sure, you are getting any data in `$_POST['zipcode']`.. etc fields ?

Comment: Same question, can you give us the output of `var_dump($_POST);` ( placeit at the beginning of your file "edit_customer.php") ?

Comment: no its just creating blank entries and sends me back to index.

Comment: `mysql` and `tsql` tags are generally incompatible. What giveth?

Comment: I figured it out. The "mysql_real_escape_string" was stripping everything out making the fields blank but not null.

Comment: Aside: your initial `SELECT` has a SQL injection vulnerability in it - this is not safe to put onto the internet yet.

Comment: Thanks. Ill look into it. I initially built it to just to get a little bit of experience with MySQL and phpMyAdmin.